# Rangeslider highlight background not working good in JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, rangeslider

I'm using a **rangeslider** with **JQuery Mobile 1.4.2** and I want change the highlight background, but I can not make it work correctly.

I've created my themes via [Theme Roller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/), I have two: theme A (image left) and theme B (image right). I want that my rangeslider be like theme B.

[image: rangesliders theme (A-left, B-rigth)]

I've tried writting the **data-track-theme** in the rangeslider but the highlight background disappear:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true" data-track-theme="b">
    <label for="range-1a">Rango de números a utilizar (1-100)</label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" >
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="30">
</div>
```

And looks like this:

[image: no highlight background]

I've tried to change the highlight background with **CSS** too:

```
.ui-slider-track{
  background: #FFCC99!important;
}
.ui-slider .ui-btn-active{
  background: #FF8000!important;
}
.ui-rangeslider .ui-btn-active{
  background: #FF8000!important;
}
```

And everything seem works good, but when I move the left control the highlight background disappear and when I move the right control the highlight background appears again.

[image: correct rangeslider highlight background]

Any idea how solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when the @ezanker answer looks good, for some reason doesn't work for me, and the problem when move the left control still. Maybe was a conflict with the JQuery Mobile themes created.

I could solved it putting the `data-track-theme="b"`in the rangesliders and deleting the first rule in CSS that I had (`ui-slider-track`). My CSS looks like this:

```
.ui-slider .ui-btn-active{
    background: #FF8000!important;
}

.ui-rangeslider .ui-btn-active{
    background: #FF8000!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting .ui-btn-active in your CSS, target .ui-slider-bg:

```
.ui-rangeslider-sliders .ui-slider-track {
    background-color: #F5CB98;
}
.ui-rangeslider-sliders .ui-slider-bg {
    background-color: #EA7E2A !important;
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wrnk86j7/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer looks great, logic and clean! I've tried demo and everything works good but for some reason doesn't work in my project, maybe there is a conflict with the themes created. The problem when move the left control still, but gonna vote you up! Thanks a lot I solved it from another way.